# ManagedObjectContext Saved In Memory, But Not On Disk

Tags: ios, core-data

I am in need of assistance... been at this for too long.

What generally is the issue when I can correctly query an NSManagedObject but when I go to check the actual datastore (after multiple context saves without fails) the data doesn't exist?

My hypothesis is that the ONLY logical conclusion is that there is a threading issue. Is this correct?

Comment: There's nothing that "generally" causes this. It could be caused by one context saving old data over new data, which might or might not be connected with threading. More detail about what you're actually doing might help narrow it down.

Comment: @user330739, do you merging changes from child MOC's as in my answer? Also, do you performing `-[commitEditing]` before MOC save?

Comment: Umm, checking the wrong data store.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If you querying objects from context, that is directly attached to persistent store, than all should be ok.

If you querying them from in-memory context, which have that directly-to-persitent-store-attached as it's parent context (which is common case for multithreaded CoreData usage), then you should push changes to parent context and then call `-[save:]` on that parent context.

*Note. I assumed, you **do** perform change merges for child MO contexts. Do you? Example code:*

```
// Core-Data MOC creation
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    _managedObjectContext = ... ; // creating context, if not yet
    ...

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        [_managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
//          //NOTE: iCloud-related
//          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(remoteChangesImport:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
    }

    // register merge callback for child contexts!
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(localChangesSave:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:_managedObjectContext];

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)localChangesSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Changes in child context. Need to merge...

    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```